# Trying to understand an `awk` code from a book by Robbins

Tags: awk

I'm reading a book `Effective AWK Programming` by Arnold Robbins and I've come across this code there which I'm trying to understand.
It should sort this and similar lists, first all numeric items and then strings:

**This first part is easy to understand**

```
BEGIN {
  data["one"] = 10
  data["two"] = 20
  data[10] = "one"
  data[100] = 100
  data[20] = "two"
  f[1] = "cmp_num_idx"
  f[2] = "cmp_str_val"
  f[3] = "cmp_num_str_val"
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    printf("Sort function: %s\n", f[i])
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = f[i]
    for (j in data)
      printf("\tdata[%s] = %s\n", j, data[j])
    print ""
  }
}
```

However I have a problem to understand why at `n2 == v2` it returns `1`
and I do not follow even this last line

`return (v1 < v2) ? -1 : (v1 != v2)`

I do understand that if `n2==v2` then `v2` was a number and not a string!

**So this is the problem:**

```
function cmp_num_str_val(i1, v1, i2, v2, n1, n2)
{
  # numbers before string value comparison, ascending order
  n1 = v1 + 0
  n2 = v2 + 0
  if (n1 == v1)
    return (n2 == v2) ? (n1 - n2) : -1
  else if (n2 == v2)
    return 1
  return (v1 < v2) ? -1 : (v1 != v2)
}
```

Can someone kindly explain to me the course of this code ?

Comment: the code `(n2 == v2) ? (n1 - n2) : -1` can be read as: When the value of `n2` is equal to `v2`, then return `(n1-n2)`, else return `-1`.   Comparing two variables can be done using `n2 == v2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if/else/if` addresses 'numeric vs numeric', and 'numeric vs string':

```
if (n1 == v1)
return (n2 == v2) ? (n1 - n2) : -1
else if (n2 == v2)
return 1

# becomes:

if (n1 == v1) {                          # v1     numeric
    if   (n2 == v2) return (n1 - n2)     #                 v2     numeric; return 0 if n1==n2; return +<number> if n1>n2; return -<number> if n1<n2
    else            return -1            #                 v2 not numeric
}
else {                                   # v1 not numeric
    if   (n2 == v2) return 1             #                 v2     numeric
}
```

If we fall through the `if/else/if` block then we're looking at 'string vs string' so we proceed to determine which of 3 string comparison outcomes apply.

```
return (v1 < v2) ? -1 : (v1 != v2)

# becomes:

if    (v1 < v2)     return -1
else                return (v1 != v2)    # return 0 if (v1 == v2); return 1 if (v1 > v2)

# or a less convoluted, more verbose, equivalent:

     if (v1 <  v2)    return -1
else if (v1 == v2)    return  0
else                  return  1          # v1 > v2
```

Comment: *"Keep in mind that v1 > v2 will write v1 to a file named (value of) v2 "* redirection to a file inside awk requires output generated using `print` (or `printf`). Even with a print statement (at least in GNU Awk 5.1.0) it won't write to a file using a number or string representation of a number value of v2 as a filename in this context.

Comment: @DavePritlove you're right; looking back through my history I (incorrectly) ran `print v1 > v2` ... should've been `print (v1 > v2)`; I've removed that line from the answer; thanks